# Begin a plot on a specific day of the week

Tags: gnuplot

I'm learning gnuplot by working on tidal data, in monthly files, in this format:

```
2011/03/01  Tue 08:42   9.39    H
2011/03/01  Tue 15:04   0.2     L
2011/03/01  Tue 21:18   8.67    H
2011/03/02  Wed 03:16   0.71    L
2011/03/02  Wed 09:31   9.51    H
2011/03/02  Wed 15:49   0.09    L
2011/03/02  Wed 22:01   8.91    H
2011/03/03  Thu 04:01   0.48    L
2011/03/03  Thu 10:14   9.58    H
2011/03/03  Thu 16:28   0.05    L
2011/03/03  Thu 22:39   9.11    H
```

All is well so far: I can output stacked plots into PDF with the multiplot layout setup, BUT I'd like to have the weekly plots always run Monday-Sunday.

With fractional weeks, especially the first week, how can I do this? I can set the xrange manually, but it would need to be re-done for each weekly plot command.

What I'd like to figure out is two things:

- a way to handle the first week problem;
- a way to automate the xrange for each succeeding week (i.e., have gnuplot parse the timestamp and start a new plot each Monday? Can I perhaps do this using the ternary operator?)

Setup:
gnuplot: version 4.4 patchlevel 2
OSX 10.6.6

Setup & plot commands:

```
set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M"
set origin 0,0
set xdata time
unset key
set samples 1000
myDate(col1,col3)=sprintf("%s-%s",strcol(1),strcol(3))
set grid noxtics
set xtics nomirror font "Arial,10" tc rgb "blue"
set xtics offset 0,0  # required for position of tic labels when stacked.
set yrange [-3:13] 
set ytics 3
set grid ytics back
set x2data time
set x2tics 86400
set grid x2tics back
set x2tics 86400
set format x2 "%d"    # displays number of day of month
set x2tics offset 3.5,-3 font "Helvetica,20"    # required for position of numbers when stacked.
#### set size 1,.2    # un-comment for setting up stacked layout.
set tmargin 3   # gives adequate room between each row of days + labels.
set lmargin 5
set bmargin 2
set rmargin 2
plot 'MonthlyTideDataMarch.txt' u (myDate(1,3)):4:xticlabels(strcol(4) . " \n" . strcol(3) ) lc rgb "green" lw 3 sm cspl notitle
```

Comment: In case this is still of interest... I don't fully understand: you have monthly data files but you want to create weekly plots. Do you want to select a certain week by date or calendar week or do you want to plot all weeks of the month in multiple plots on one canvas or maybe all weekly plots on top of each other? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bash script for this and use the "date" program. You probable need to tweak the date formats, etc., but in principle;) this should work...

```
# write dates into a temporary file, create a date range
# for each line in your input file
echo -n ""> tmp.out
while read line; do
      d=${line:0:22}
      y=$(date --date "$d" +%Y)
      w=$(date --date "$d" +%W)
      M=$(date --date "$y-01-01 +$w weeks -1 week +2 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
      S=$(date --date "$y-01-01 +$w weeks -1 week +8 day" +%Y-%m-%d)
      echo '"'$M'":"'$S'"' >> tmp.out
done < data.txt

# make them unique
uniq tmp.out > dates.out

# create a gnuplot input file, needs your code from above
cat <<EOF > in.gnu
reset
EOF

# add a plot command for each date range. 
# needs your plot command and perhaps more plot specific data (title, etc.)
while read line; do
   cat <<EOF >>in.gnu
   set xrange [$line]
   plot "data.txt" u 1:2
EOF
done < dates.out
```

the script generates a gnuplot input file that you can then run on your data.